# can someone check my coding here pls

Tags: vbscript

This VBScript should get a random number between 1 and 3, and then type the letter according to the number and type it into the notepad that it opened and then goto the next line, but for some reason it doesn't enter the letter. Can someone explain the problem to me please? Here is the code:

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ws.Run "notepad.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 100

do

RAND = Int((3 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

if RAND=1 Then
    key = a
elseif RAND=2 Then
    key = b
elseif RAND=3 Then
    key = c
end if

ws.SendKeys key
ws.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.sleep 1000

loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key="a"
```

Place `Option Explicit` as the first line of the file and you will see that you are trying to assign non defined variables instead of string literals

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `a`, `b`, `c`?

Maybe you mean:

```
if RAND=1 Then
    key = "a"
elseif RAND=2 Then
    key = "b"
elseif RAND=3 Then
    key = "c"
end if
```

Comment: Stupid is not making a mistake; stupid is repeating the same mistake :)